# Azure Data Factory: Delete an Empty Directory Issue

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

Within an Azure Data Factory Pipeline I am attempting to remove an empty directory.

The files within the directory were removed by a previous pipelines' iterative operation thus leaving an empty directory to be removed.

The directory is a sub-folder: The hierarchy being:

container / top-level-folder (always present) / directory - dynamically created - the result of an unzip operation.

I have defined a specific dataset that points to

container / @concat('top-level-folder/',dataset().dataset_folder)

where 'dataset_folder' is the only parameter.

The Delete Activity is configured like this:

[image]

On running the pipeline it errors with this error:

**Failed to execute delete activity with data source 'AzureBlobStorage' and error 'The required Blob is missing. Folder path: container/top level directory/Directory to be removed/.'. For details, please reference log file here:**

The log is an empty spreadsheet.

What am I missing from either the dataset or delete activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an Azure function suggested here:
[Delete folder using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob : blockBlob.DeleteAsync();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74447381/delete-folder-using-microsoft-windowsazure-storage-blob-blockblob-deleteasync/74449166#74449166)

to perform the action.

Answer (score 0):

In azure blob storage, when all the contents inside a folder are deleted, then the folder would automatically get deleted.

- When I deleted each file and tried to delete the folder in the end, then I got the same error.

[image]

- This is because the folder is deleted as soon as the files in the folders are deleted. Only when using azure data lake storage, you will have to specifically delete the folder as well.
- Since the requirement is to delete the folder in azure blob storage, you can simply remove the delete activity that you are using to remove the folder.

Comment: I currently have the Directory (which is a child directory) sitting empty. 
From what I can see the expected hierarchy is
CONTAINER | FOLDER | FILE
in my case it is 
CONTAINER | FOLDER | CHILD FOLDER - Dynamically created- | FILE 
would that complicate the automatic deletion?

Comment: You are using blob storage. And your hierarchy is container/folder/files (files will be deleted) and you want the folder to be deleted later? Is this Right?

Comment: container/folder/child_folder/files
It is the child_folder that is emptied that seems to be sticking around.

Comment: I have rechecked. Even with the same hierarchy structure, the folder gets automatically deleted if it is empty (for blob storage). Try refreshing and checking again.

Comment: The folder is still present, empty except for the [..] parent level link.

Comment: Lets say you have `data` container, `main` as parent folder and `sub` as child folder, you deleted files in sub folder and now want to delete the folder itself. But the `sub` folder still exists and error is thrown when tried to delete it. Try to add an image of the folder hierarchy if this is not the case.

Comment: I just want to delete the empty sub-folder.