# Delete folder using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob : blockBlob.DeleteAsync();

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-function-async

I am using C# in an Azure HTTP Trigger to remove an empty blob storage child folder.
I have obtained the URI of the child folder and setup the security token access to the storage.

However, when I invoke the method:

**blockBlob.DeleteAsync();**

While this is successful, the folder is not removed?

Is there a better mechanism for removing a blob folder (that does not get removed when empty)
using .NET C# approach?

Should I be passing parameters and invoking a different version of this method?

Comment: Is your storage account ADLS Gen2 or regular blob storage account?

Comment: StorageV2 (general purpose v2)

Comment: Accessed via https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer

Comment: Please check if hierarchical namespace is enabled on the storage account. You should not have empty blob folders in a regular storage account.

Comment: Data Lake Storage
Hierarchical namespace  Enabled
Default access tier           Hot
Blob public access           Enabled

Comment: Blob soft delete Disabled

Container soft delete Disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering hierarchical namespace is enabled for the storage account, the SDK you would want to use is [`Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake).

To delete a directory, your code would be something like (taken from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-dotnet#delete-a-directory)):

```
public void DeleteDirectory(DataLakeFileSystemClient fileSystemClient)
{
    DataLakeDirectoryClient directoryClient =
        fileSystemClient.GetDirectoryClient("my-directory");

    directoryClient.Delete();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give this approach a try. I will write with the outcome.

Comment: I am now running into 404 PathNotFound on a Uri object being passed into 

directoryClient.Delete();

That has a format of 

https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myparentfolder/Folder_To_Delete

Comment: Altered some of the paths was getting confused with URI, the GetDirectoryClient appends the folder name that explains the 404. The process is now working.